# Laravel кол-во созданых заметок авторизованым пользоватлем

Tags: php, laravel

class MainController extends Controller
{
    public function main(){

```
    return view('welcome', [
        'count_title' => DB::table('notes')->where('user_id','=',Auth::id())->count()
    ]);

}
```

}

Пытаюсь составить запрос , но не получается  скрин бд
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что значит не получается? Какая ошибка? Вызовите вместо count () , dd() и посмотрите как строится запрос.

Answer (score 0):

В контроллере сделал вот такое нехитрое действие 
 public function main(){

```
    $value = Note::where('user_id','=',Auth::id())->get();
    $valueCount = $value->count();

    return view('welcome', [
        'count_title' => $valueCount
    ]);
```